# Failed Kasm Workspace installation on Ubuntu Server 23.10 LTS On raspberry pi 4 7895Mib of memory

Tags: ubuntu

I was trying to install Kasm Workspace on Ubuntu Server 23.10 LTS and I received this error:

Setting Seed file as /opt/kasm/1.10.0/conf/database/seed_data/default_properties.yaml
yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 22: mapping key "restart" already defined at line 6 line 39: mapping key "restart" already defined at line 34
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: kasm_db: No such container: kasm_db
Error response from daemon: No such container: kasm_db
kasm_db_1.10. 0
kasm_db_1. 10.0
yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 22: mapping key "restart" already defined at line 6 line 39: mapping key "restart" already defined at line 34

—————————————————————-
I have not been able to resolve the problem.

Thanks
—CS—

[image]